# (Java Game Modding)How to delay this with nano time?

Tags: java, timer

I'm programming a forcefield mod for Minecraft(a game.)

Here is my code so far:

```
    if (Camb.killaura)
    {      
        for(final int i= 0; i < mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.size(); i++){
            if((Entity)mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.get(i) != this && getDistanceSqToEntity((Entity)mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.get(i)) < 19.5D){
                if(((Entity)mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.get(i) instanceof EntityPlayer)){
                        mc.playerController.attackEntity(this, (Entity)mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.get(i));
                            swingItem();
                    }

            }
```

Everything works, but the issue is most servers only allow you to attack an entity 8 times a second. So my question is, how can I execute the following every .125 seconds? I asked a few  fellow modders and they say they use nanoseconds, how can I do this?

This is the only code that needs the delay:

```
mc.playerController.attackEntity(this, (Entity)mc.theWorld.loadedEntityList.get(i));
                        swingItem();
```

Comment: Using nanotime is a bit too precise for this. Depending on the thread that's being run using microtime would be better, perhaps if the thread can sleep( without causing a game hang for 0.125 seconds.

Comment: @hexafraction Yeah I used thread.sleep before, screen turns black.